# Auto-creation of tags upon % of tries and no submission from users?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-creation

Hi,

It would be interesting if the website could auto create tags that are often picked by the users without enough access to create it. For example, if a given tag has X% of tries and no other user has submited it yet.

How would the system recognize it ?
when creating a question the system would verify once the user has finished writting on the tag fields or upon the post your question click

Some might think it is a useless thing but i belive it would make it more complete where some times we tend to forget some important tags that might be around ...

Comment: What's an example of a tag that this would be necessary for? Part of the reason the tag creation threshold had been raised was to restrict who could actually create tags - the emphasis being a value of experience in knowing the tag system rather than a matter of popularity.

Comment: Currently i can't recall of any as they do not happen that often but it does happen so let's play with an example: Let's say the tag C# has never been registered yet... it is not bad that it gets auto-created if you have an amount of 1k members and none of them have submited it yet but 70% of those have tried but could not due to limitations ... ofc this was just an example but there are tags that we might not recall to register but LOTS of people may have tried it without success due to the fact of the limitations and perhaps no one with access went thru it yet ...

Comment: `It would still maintain the restriction but based on a % of tries of a given tag it would auto-create it.`

Comment: @GraceNote - examples of tags I recently tried to use on codereview.stackexchange.com: 'responsive-design', 'media-queries' and oddly enough 'code-review' (although perhaps 'review-request' would be better?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see the problem you are trying to solve:
If the tag in question wasn't registered yet but describes the question well, one of the usual editor suspects or others users with sufficient reputation will surely add it.
Alternatively you can always leave a comment a la: *"This should have the `[waffles]` tag, if someone would be so kind... ?"*.

Additionally this would introduce the same problem again:
The restriction on tag creation exists because users regularly added new non-sense tags (e.g. ["objective"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective) if they entered `objective c`). With your suggestion we'd have that problem again if only enough users make the same mistake.

Comment: True, it is an option... but i don't belive this would be a bad idea either ... I mean there is no loss to it other then having more tags registered and available for users and being tracked by search engines ... The point to it is also about forgetfull users and tags and not at those that usually remember about it in the sense of asking for someone to create it and the sorts.

Comment: @Prix: This would circumvent the restriction for the cases that it should block in the first place - nonsense tags could be introduced again.

Comment: In addition, we do have a lot of users with sufficient reputation ambling about - they will often fix tags and create new ones even without people needing to ask. So that can often take care of the forgetful users.

Comment: I belive it would be very hard to have 70% of the community trying to add nonsense tags ...

Comment: @Prix: 70% users trying would make nearly any automatic tag addition impossible - remember that there is a great diversity of user groups. If you lower the number far enough that it can react quickly to new technologies you get the nonsense tag problem again. Simply letting trusted users add tags *works now* and solves both problems sufficiently.